# Is it possible to unfreeze the execution of systemd without reboot?

Tags: systemd

Switching betweem tty's is possible.

SysRQ is unfortunately disabled.

Is there any way to unfreeze *systemd*?

Comment: How do you know `systemd` is frozen and not the kernel ?

Comment: @MarkStosberg Linux only printed `systemd[1]: Freezing Execution`, not kernel. If the kernel was frozen, I would not be able to switch tty's. Is a frozen kernel not equivalent to a kernel panic? The systemd execution stopped when Inpressed the power button to unfreeze my computer due to SQUASHFS errors caused by the optical drive being not ready directly after waking the laptop up from the suspended state. After the DVD drive was available again after reading the boot DVD, Linux did not try correcting the SquashFS errors by re-reading them from the DVD while new applications still opened.

Comment: All of that needs to be in the question.

Answer (score 4):

No. [Once in "freeze" mode, systemd doesn't provide service anymore and system can only be rebooted](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1437114).

You may be able to run `systemctl reboot --force --force` in some cases, but this would be hardly better and then just pressing and holding the power button.

(I found the above answer as the first result as a web search for "systemd freezing execution".)

Answer (score 2):

If you can log in on the tty, you can use `sudo journalctl -xe` to view the log starting at the most recent entries - that may give you a clue as to why it's frozen.